# Why image tag doesn't shrink same as any text block in html?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

May i please allow myself a little stupid question? Yes, ty
I've been working on one project and met following structure of elements:

its a section divided 70/30 into 2 left and right halfs. 
Each hals has text + icon in it with an exception that left one has inline following Text(1st) and ICON(2nd) to the right of text. And second one has icon on top of text.

Here is a screenshot for better understanding:
[image]

Html structure is following:

```html
<div class="block-wrapper">
    <img src="icon.png" height="140" width="130" alt="blabla" />
    <div class="text-block">Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
</div>
```

blocks are in main wrapper which is flexbox.

What i want is an image to shrink when the browser's width shrinks. 
If u simply place 2 divs blocks with text inside flex container and start shrinking browser's width it will decrease size of 2 divs simultaneously. I want same with my **img** tag

I know about max-width: 100% and width: 100% properties but this is not the case.

Only solution i found is to make a div wrapper with % width around image and say max-width: 100% to image, but i don't like it. Any other solutions ideas to solve it ? Again, my font size decreases with less width and i want an image to decrease its size as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/Julesezaar/64otbdw7/

Comment: Can you provide a working example, e.g. in snippet, Codepen or any other tool?

Comment: Something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/Julesezaar/64otbdw7/ Just remove width="xx" and height="xx" from img elements. And set them in % with css. so they will be relative to the container. Height must be set to auto then:

Comment: kinda so, thx for making a fiddle. i will stick it to my post. you can see image changes size when browser width gets smaller. that's because of wrapper and width percentage on image. how to do same but without wrapper around div.

Comment: also with this approach - img { width : 50% } you cannot prevent image from growing bigger than it's default sizes(real sizes) which you can do with max-width: 100%.
what if u don't need image to go very big on high reso screens ?

Comment: Please put your example code in the post itself, not on some external site that might stop working (or change).

Comment: ok i will upload tomorrow. its late

Comment: Okay after really long long time and efforts i found two solutions to this.

If you want both of your text and img near it to resize simultaneously, you can go 2 ways: 

1) Put a div wrapper around img tag. Wrapper should have % width based on what sizes u want. Tag img inside of it should have max-width:100% and height: auto set up. 

2) Is to give your img and (important) your text block(in my case its div) a width percentage. I did 70% for text and 30% for img. Then apply object-fit: contain to img and you are good. Height: auto not working in this case